# SyntaxError: Identifier 'MongoClient' has already been declared

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting an error in console, can you please help I am trying to run my express server.
my goal is to be able to run the server.js.

```
import app from './server';
import mongodb, { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

MongoClient.connect(process.env.RESTREVIEWS_DB_URI, {
  maxPoolSize: 50,
  wtimeoutMS: 2500,
  useNewUrlParser: true,
})
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  })
  .then(async (client) => {
    app.listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`listening on port ${port}`);
    });
  });
```

Then the console is showing after I run server.js

> file:///C:/Users/jayde/Desktop/react/restaurant-reviews/backend/index.js:5
> const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;

> ```
> SyntaxError: Identifier 'MongoClient' has already been declared
>     at Loader.moduleStrategy (internal/modules/esm/translators.js:145:18)
>     at async link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:64:21)
> [nodemon]
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are already importing `MongoClient` here:

```js
import mongodb, { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
                  here it is
```

… it does not make sense to import it again here:

```
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
      remove this
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import mongodb, { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
```

This line defines two constants: `mongodb` and `MongoClient`.
So it throws an error when you try to make another variable called `MongoClient`.

```js
const MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
```

You should be able to remove that whole line and it should work.